# No module named django.shortcuts

Tags: python, django

I am creating a Django project but I have run into a problem. In my views.py file, my Wing IDE debugger on Ubuntu says:

```
File "/home/deanna/django_test/article/views.py", line 1, in <module>
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

ImportError: No module named django.shortcuts
```

Here is my views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from article.models import Article
from django.http import HttpResponse
#import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
# Create your views here.

def articles(request):
    language = 'en-us'
    session_language = 'en-us'

    if 'lang' in request.COOKIES:
        language = request.COOKIES['lang']

    return render_to_response('articles.html',  
                          {'articles':
                           Article.objects.all(), 'language' : language })

def article(request, article_id=1):
    return render_to_response('article.html', {'article': 
  Article.objects.get(id=article_id)}}                                    
#The line above is supposed to be properly indented but Stack Overflow isn't letting me do that.

def language(request, language='en-us'):
    response = HttpResponse("setting language to %s" % language)


    response.set_cookie('lang', language)

    return response
```

And when I run the webpage on my localhost, I get this error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/all/

Using the URLconf defined in django_test.urls, Django tried these URL  patterns, in this order:

    ^all/$
    ^get/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$
    ^language/(?P<language>[a-z\-]+)/$

The current URL, articles/all/, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django  settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

I have created a urls.py file and a settings.py file. Both of which have no errors. I also have an articles.html and an article.html file and those have no errors either. 
The filepaths for the files:

```
urls.py- /home/(my name)/django_test/article
views.py- /home/(my name)/django_test/article
settings.py- /home/(my name)/django_test/django_test
articles.html- /home/(my name)/django_test/article/templates
article.html- /home/(my name)/django_test/article/templates
```

I downloaded django.shortcuts into my django_test file but I don't know why the debugger is complaining or why my web page isn't loading. Thank you.

Comment: On the second error, looks like your /articles/all/ path is not defined on urls.py, create one like this ^articles/all/$

Comment: Do you have a file or a package named django in your app? Most likely that is overriding the default django

Comment: If you're using a virtual env, have you enabled it in your IDE's settings?

Comment: *"I downloaded django.shortcuts into my django_test file"*. Why? As in, why not simply install Django itself; then it'll find `django.shortcuts` by itself. Probably now, you'll need something like `from shortcuts import ...` or even `from django_test.shortcuts import ...`.

Comment: @karthikr: not inside my django_test folder. But I have an empty django folder and a django-(my name) folder that's not empty. But I have another file named settings.py  and a second urls.py file in the django_test2 folder inside django-(my name). Am I supposed to only have one settings.py file and one urls.py file in my app?

Comment: @Evert: I did install Django. I'm confused. Should I delete django.shortcuts?

Comment: You should be using the default django shortcuts. You should not be downloading anything explicitly.

Comment: @karthikr: I moved the files I downloaded into the trash. But it still shows the same error.

Comment: @avenet: I added ^articles/all/$ but the site still doesn't work.

Comment: I just realized the Wing IDE might not know about Django. How do I let it know?

Comment: @brown1001 Can you show the error after adding ^articles/all/?

Comment: @avenet: 
    Page not found (404)
    Request Method:  GET
    Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/all/

    Using the URLconf defined in django_test.urls, Django tried these  URL patterns, in this order:

        ^all/$
        ^get/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$
        ^language/(?P<language>[a-z\-]+)/$

    The current URL, articles/all/, didn't match any of these.

    You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

Comment: @brown1001 Looks like you didn't add the path ^articles/all/ in urls.py, because it should appear on the 404 error...

Comment: Did it. The site works now. Thank you everybody.

Answer (score 0):

When you face these types of errors:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.shortscuts'
```

First check the spelling is right:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect
```